# Binding a ReactiveList<enum> to a combo box

Tags: c#, wpf, enums, reactiveui

I've seen lots of solutions for binding a ReactiveList to a ComboBox control in WPF such that the control displays the enum items' descriptions. All of these solutions use a standard TypeConverter and binding in the XAML, but I'm using ReactiveUI, so I want to do the bindings in the code behind. Without any sort of conversion, I get the raw enum values as strings rather than their descriptions, so at least I know the binding is working properly, but I haven't figured out the conversion.

I'm pretty sure that I need to use an IBindingTypeConverter (and register it using Splat), but I can't seem to find the right combination of toType and fromType in my converter to make this happen. I tried the following with partial success:

```
public class MyEnumToStringConverter : IBindingTypeConverter
{
    public int GetAffinityForObjects(Type fromType, Type toType)
    {
        if (fromType == tyepof(ReactiveList<MyEnumType>))
        {
            return 100;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public bool TryConvert(object from, Type toType, object conversionHint, out object result)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

In the debugger, GetAffinityForObjects() gets hit and returns 100 during the call to bind the ComboBox's ItemsSource, but TryConvert never gets called.

Can anyone provide a nice example for doing this the Right Way in ReactiveUI?

Comment: to get something like a description, I use a combination of DisplayName attribute and a extension method, works on any app and with xaml a IBindingTypeConverter

Comment: The point here is to do the binding in the code behind and _not_ in the XAML.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea its a lot of stuff:
The `Display` its part of `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace but you can use another and just change `DisplayName` method

```
public enum CoolEnum {
    [Display(Name="Value 1")]
    Value1,
    [Display(Name="Value 2")]
    Value2,
}

public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static string DisplayName(this Enum value)
    {
        Type enumType = value.GetType();
        var enumValue = Enum.GetName(enumType, value);
        MemberInfo member = enumType.GetMember(enumValue)[0];

        var attrs = member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false);
        var outString = ((DisplayAttribute)attrs[0]).Name != null ? ((DisplayAttribute)attrs[0]).Name : enumValue; //TODO Null check

        if (((DisplayAttribute)attrs[0]).ResourceType != null)
        {
            outString = ((DisplayAttribute)attrs[0]).GetName();
        }

        return outString;
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var enumValue = CoolEnum.Value1;
var displayValue = enumValue.DisplayName();
```

In XAML could use ValueConverter

```
public class EnumToDisplayName : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try 
        {
            var enumValue = (CoolEnum)value;
            return enumValue.DisplayName();
        }
        catch (Exception){
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return System.Windows.DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

Inside XAML stuff where you bind the data, map the converter as resource and use it:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:EnumToDisplayValue x:Key="enumToDisplayValue" />
</UserControl.Resources>

Text="{Binding enumValue, Converter={StaticResource enumToDisplayValue}}"
```

Just an idea to start, have fun coding :)

Comment: The point of the question was to do this in a way that could use ReactiveUI binding methods in the code behind rather than bindings in the XAML. While your implementation will work, it doesn't satisfy the requirement of removing bindings from the XAML, and isn't a ReactiveUI-based implementation.